# Why wordpress word count differs from Microsoft word and sites like wordcounter.net

Tags: editor

My authors are questioning the accuracy of word count in wordpress. Wordpress word count seems to vary from microsoft word document and sites like wordcounter.net
Moreover, I manually created php function to calculate the word count which seems to be somewhat accurate to word doc but still different from wordpress word count.

Which one is more accurate and how wordpress calculates?

Answer (score 4):

WordPress removes HTML entities, convert connectors (-- or em-dash) to spaces, removes unwated characters (General Punctuation, Superscripts and Subscripts, Currency Symbols, Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols, Letterlike Symbols, Number Forms, Arrows, Mathematical Operators, Miscellaneous Technical, Control Pictures, Optical Character Recognition, Enclosed Alphanumerics, Box Drawing, Block Elements, Geometric Shapes, Miscellaneous Symbols, Dingbats, Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-A, Supplemental Arrows-A, Braille Patterns, Supplemental Arrows-B, Miscellaneous Mathematical Symbols-B, Supplemental Mathematical Operators, Miscellaneous Symbols and Arrows), removes UTF-16 surrogate points.

You can see js code in `wp-admin/js/word-count.js`

On my test site, even for quite complicated generated test posts word count is the same. For example, http://test.kagg.eu/at-commodi-quia-enim/ shows 622 as in WordPress, so in Word.

Question what counter is more accurate has not too much sense, as different software defines term "word" on its own.